# stubs generation - JAX WS or JAX RPC, which one to use, when we are provided with a WSDL

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

Will there be any difference between the stubs generated by JAX WS and JAX RPC standard? can we use one of this to generate the stubs from a WSDL or we have to check for any criteria to pick one of these.

If we have to choose one of the approach, how to decide what to choose, when provided with a WSDL

Answer (score 1):

Just use JAX-WS.

JAX-RPC has been deprecated in favor of JAX-WS since many years ago already. Its intent was to use Remote Prodecure Calls style to call SOAP web services and after some time, it was substituted by JAX-WS.

In other words, JAX-WS was the successor to JAX-RPC.

There's a small exception though, and that is if you have to send an encoded-style SOAP message, then you would have to use JAX-RPC. But unless you have to develop a client for a very old web service, you will not want to do that, since encoded messages are not [WS-I Basic Profile compliant](http://ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.2-2010-11-09.html).

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/) you can see the diferences between the two libraries.